# Is "clothes" the plural of "cloth"?

Tags: grammar

Is clothes the plural of cloth like should i treat cloth as a countable noun since we can say"the clothes i bought are so expensive "

Comment: Cloths is plural for cloth

Comment: try https://www.etymonline.com/word/clothes

Comment: @user47014 Yes. "Clothes" is an uncountable noun - only used in the plural. There is no singular, though one can talk about someone's "clothing".

Comment: "clothes" is also the singular agreeing form of the verb "clothe". "He clothes his thoughts in song."

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

The [plural form of cloth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloth) is cloths. Clothes are articles of clothing. Clothes are made of cloth, and when worn out can be used as cloths, but clothes and cloths are not the same.